# Como faço para o Python não ligar para as letras maiúsculas ou minúsculas do código?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Código:

```
while(1):
    x= str (input ('Meu avô tinha dois cachorros, um se chamava Pet e o outro se chamava Repete, o Pet morreu, quem é que ficou?'))
    if x != 'Repete':
        print("Errado!")
        break
```

A ideia do código é aquela velha piada sem graça do 5° ano, ou seja, toda vez que alguém digitar "Repete", o programa vai ficar repetindo, o problema é que se o usuário escrever "repete" ao em vez de "Repete", o código quebra, não faço ideia de como resolver isso.

Comment: Use os métodos [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) ou [`str.upper()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) para obter uma cópia da entra em minúsculas ou maiúsculas e faça a comparação: `if x.upper() != 'REPETE':`

Comment: E aqui `x= str (input ('Meu avô...` esse `str` é desnecessário input já retorna uma string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Observe que este programa, assim como o próprio autor disse, é uma piada de mau gosto.**

O intuito deste programa é, caso o usuário digite a resposta **CERTA** o programa seja reexecutado. E, caso a resposta seja **ERRADA** o programa exibe uma mensagem de erro e encerra.

> A ideia do código é aquela velha piada sem graça do 5° ano, ou seja, toda vez que alguém digitar "Repete", o programa vai ficar repetindo...

De acordo com esta parte do enunciado devemos perceber que o programa **SEMPRE** repetirá caso a palavra digitada seja `repete`, independentemente se seus caracteres forem maiúsculos ou minúsculos ou misturados.

Uma das formas para resolver esta questão é utilizando [expressão de atribuição](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=walrus#assignment-expressions). Dessa forma podemos:

1. Capturar a resposta e converter todos os seus caracteres para maiúsculos;
2. Verificar se esta resposta, de fato, é `REPETE`;
3. Reexecutar o laço ou encerrar o programa.

Uma forma que podemos implementar código é:

```
def fato():
    return 'Meu avô tinha dois cachorros. Um se chamava Pet e o outro ' \
           'se chamava Repete. O Pet morreu.'


while (n := input(f'{fato()} \nQuem é que ficou? ').upper()) == 'REPETE':
    '\t'
print("ERRADO!")
```

Pois bem, enquanto a resposta do usuário for a resposta certa de acordo com a pergunta, o programa será novamente reexecutado. E, caso a resposta seja **ERRADA** de acordo com a pergunta, o programa irá exibir uma mensagem de erro e  encerrará automaticamente.

**Testando o código:**

Ao executar o programa, enquanto digitarmos os caracteres pertencentes à palavra repete, na ordem em que os mesmos faz sentido, independentemente que os mesmos sejam maiúsculos ou minúsculos, o programa será reexecutado. Caso contrário, o programa nos exibirá a mensagem `ERRADO` e encerrará a execução.

---

Agora se você não quiser utilizar a **axpressão de atribuição**, você pode implementar o seguinte código:

```
while 1:
    x = input('Meu avô tinha dois cachorros, um se chamava Pet e o outro se chamava Repete. '
              'O Pet morreu. \nQuem é que ficou? ').capitalize()
    if x != 'Repete':
        print("Errado!")
        break
```

Observe que este código é a forma corrigida do código apresentado na pergunta.

**Primeira correção:**

Os parênteses que envolve o valor **1** são desnecessários. Por isso os removei.

**Segunda correção:**

A função **str()** é desnecessária, uma vez que o retorna da função **input()** sempre será uma string. Por isso a removi.

**Terceira correção:**

Se você pretende compara a resposta com a string **Repete**, você precisa converter a string digitada com a função **capitalize**. Por isso, inseri a referida função ao final da função **input()**.

**Quarta correção:**

**A principal função do programa é repetir a pergunta, caso a resposta do usuário esteja correta** e, caso contrário, exibe a mensagem **Errado!** e **ENCERRA** a execução do programa. Por isso é desnecessário exibir as mensagens **Acertou!** ou **Você acertou!**.

Comment: Muito obrigado, explicou de uma forma muito clara para mim.

Answer (score 5):

Como já foi dito nos comentários:

> Use os métodos [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) ou [`str.upper()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) para obter uma cópia da entrada em minúsculas ou maiúsculas e faça a comparação.

> Aplicar uma conversão de [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#func-str) a saída de um [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#input) é desnecessário pois o retorno de input já é uma string.

No exemplo a expressão `x:= input(pergunta).upper() != 'REPETE'` pode ser entendida assim:

1. É atribuído `input(pergunta).upper()` a `x` por meio de uma [expressão de atribuição](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=walrus#assignment-expressions)(operador walrus) `x:= input(pergunta).upper()`.
2. É feita comparação se `x != 'REPETE'`.

O resultado dessa expressão é testado a cada iteração do `while`.

```
pergunta = 'Meu avô tinha dois cachorros.\nUm se chamava Pet e o outro se chamava Repete.\nO Pet morreu, quem é que ficou?\n'

while(x:= input(pergunta).upper() != 'REPETE'):
  print("Errado!")
print("Você acertou!")
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/PetRepete#main.py)</sup>

Comment: Acho que vale dizer que o [operador `:=`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions) foi introduzido na versão 3.8 - em versões anteriores o jeito é usar as soluções das outras respostas

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de resolver essa questão mantendo o seu código seria da seguinte forma, usando a função `capitalize()`

```
while(1):
    x= input('Meu avô tinha dois cachorros, um se chamava Pet e o outro se chamava Repete, o Pet morreu, quem é que ficou?')
    if x.capitalize() != 'Repete':
        print("Errado!")
        break
    else:
        print("acertou")
```

Answer (score -1):

Estou aprendendo python, e vi essa dúvida. Tentei resolver, e fiz dessa forma.

def repete():

```
palavra = ['repete','Repete','REPETE']
for i in enumerate(palavra):
    resp = input('\nMeu avô tinha dois cachorros, um se chamava Pet e o outro se chamava Repete, o Pet morreu, quem é que ficou? \n')
    if resp in i:
        repete()
    else:
        print('errado!')
        break
```

repete()